# Regex needed - String1 String2 | String3 String4

Tags: regex

I'm having a bit of a trouble with regexps...

I've tried out a few websites with regexp generators, but none helped me... so.. here I am...

I need a regexp that grabs ONLY the first 2 strings before the pipe...

So basically I just want to stay with:

**INPUT: String_1 String_2 | String_3 String_4**

**OUTPUT: String_1 String_2**

This one catches all of the words.. ([A-Z])\w+ and I just need the information before the pipe... :'(

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^([A-Z]\w* +[A-Z]\w*)(?= *\|)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dE0vK9/1)

Comment: If it worked out you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick mark on top left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you could do like this,

```
.*?(?=\s*\|)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-greedy Regex to do it quite succinctly:

```
([\S\s]+?)\|
```

Will get everything before the pipe

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a split on pipe, but if you really want a regex:

```
^([^|]+)
```

This will capture (in group 1) everything that is not a pipe from the begining of the string.

If you want to capture the 2 groups:

```
^([^|]+) | (.*)$
```

With your example,

`String_1 String_2` will be in group 1 and `String_3 String_4` in group 2.

The implementation depends on the language you're using.
For example, in PHP:

```
$str = 'String_1 String_2 | String_3 String_4';
preg_match('/^([^|]+) | (.*)$/', $str, $match);
//$match[1] : String_1 String_2
//$match[2] : String_3 String_4
```

Comment: Ok so... what if I want to use all these regex's (Thanks a lot guys!! :D ) but I want to choose the field I'm using?

For example:
-> Field 1 = String_1 String_2
-> Field 2 = String_3 String_4

Comment: @user3653103: It depends on the language you're using. See my edit